# Jquery - Parent Selector (closest)

Tags: jquery

How to select a class which is the parent from a parent?

**js**

```
<div onclick="$('.al_head.tt_this).closest('.aledmsg').remove();" style="cursor:pointer;"> TEST </div>
```

**html**

```
<div id="albox">

    <div class="al_head" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" id="alss"> <img  src="bt.png" alt="se">
    <div style="float: left; width: 282px;" class="aledmsg"><strong>Feexts</strong>
      <hr>
      <div class="ams" id="xc98f">blub</div>
      <div class="ams tt_this" id="xb697">blib <-</div>
      <div class="ams" id="x56b1">blab</div>
      <div class="ams tt_this" id="xb214">blnb <-</div>
       <div class="ams tt_this" id="xb997">blmb <-</div>      
    </div>
  </div>
           <br />   <br />
    <div class="al_head_2" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" id="alss"> <img  src="bt.png" alt="se">
    <div style="float: left; width: 282px;" class="aledmsg_2"><strong>Feexts 2</strong>
      <hr>
      <div class="ams" id="xc98f">blub</div>
      <div class="ams tt_this" id="xb697">blib <-</div>
      <div class="ams" id="x56b1">blab</div>
      <div class="ams tt_this" id="xb214">blnb <-</div>
       <div class="ams tt_this" id="xb997">blmb <-</div>      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RAN9C/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're after:

```
$('#albox .tt_this').closest('.aledmsg').remove();
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RAN9C/14/), the quotes don't match on the initial selector and the `.tt_this` class is on a child, not directly on the `#albox` `<div>`.